# How do you determine if a spritenode is not equal to nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

So in Obj-C I used to do it like this:

```
SKSpriteNode *someNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"foo"];
someNode.position = CGPointMake(100,100);
someNode.size = CGSizeMake(100,100);
[self addChild:someNode]

//I'd test it like this:
if (someNode) {
  //Do something
}

//I could also do it like this:
if (someNode != nil) {
   //Do something
}
```

However, when I want to achieve the same thing in swift, it gives me the error: *Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SKSpriteNode' and 'nil'*

I did it like this:

```
if someNode != nil {
  //Do something
}
```

I also tried this:

```
if someNode {
  //Do something
}
```

This gives me the error: *Type 'SKSpriteNode' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'*

Is there a way to test if a node already exists?

Comment: Look-up "optionals" in the Swift documentation :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have to consider that `SKSpriteNode` node derive from `SKNode`, so it inherits all its properties according to *Apple* doc [SKNode Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/):

In **Swift 2.x** the best general way to do is:

```
if let someNodeExist = self.childNodeWithName("\\someNode") {
        print("\(someNodeExist.debugDescription)")
    }
```

In **Swift 3.x**:

```
if let someNodeExist = self.childNode(withName: "\\someNode") {
        print("\(someNodeExist.debugDescription)")
}
```

or using guard:

```
guard let someNodeExist = self.childNode(withName: "\\someNode") else { return }
```

After that you can check which kind of class is someNodeExist or casting directly to SKSpriteNode, you decide.